# Group repeated rows to one row in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I write a code in Bigquery from multiple same data to only one row? Total Revenue contains null value. I'm still new with sql and would like to ask some help.

FROM THIS: RAW DATA

| ID | People | Product | Total Price | Total Revenue | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | Anna | Eyeliner | 200 | 1500 | 30% |
| 2345 | Anna | Pencil eyeliner | 200 | 1500 | 30% |
| 2345 | Anna | Liquid eyeliner | 200 | 1500 | 30% |
| 2345 | Anna | Pen eyeliner | 200 | 1500 | 30% |
| 2345 | Anna | Gel eyeliner | 200 | 1500 | 30% |
| 5423 | Arnold | Lipstick | 300 | 2000 | 35% |
| 5423 | Arnold | Lipgloss | 300 | 2000 | 35% |
| 5423 | Arnold | Liptint | 300 | 2000 | 35% |

TO RESULT NEEDED:

| ID | People | Product | Total Price | Total Revenue | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | Anna | Eyeliner | 200 | 1500 | 30% |
| 2345 | Anna | Pencil eyeliner |  |  |  |
| 2345 | Anna | Liquid eyeliner |  |  |  |
| 2345 | Anna | Pen eyeliner |  |  |  |
| 2345 | Anna | Gel eyeliner |  |  |  |
| 5423 | Arnold | Lipstick | 300 | 2000 | 35% |
| 5423 | Arnold | Lipgloss |  |  |  |
| 5423 | Arnold | Liptint |  |  |  |

Thanks in advance!

I did try string_agg but the null values in total revenue creates an error

Comment: `null` entries are not allowed in an array. Please use `string_agg(Product ignore nulls)`

Comment: Hi Samuel. Thank you for your help. What if the data type is float?

Comment: why is the data type float? Please give more details. `ignore nulls` also works with floats. You need to group by all columns, but `Product`. `Select ID,People, Total_Price, Total_Revenue, Percentage,  string_agg(Product ignore nulls) from .... group by 1,2,3,4,5 `